# find the filename from a string with php

Tags: php, path

```
public/images/portfolio/i-vis/1.jpg
```

How could i remove all the path regardless of what the filename is using php?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have a look at [`basename()`](http://bg.php.net/basename)

```
$path = 'public/images/portfolio/i-vis/1.jpg'
$name = basename($path); // $name == '1.jpg'
```

Also, [`dirname()`](http://bg.php.net/dirname) fetches the other part

```
$dir = dirname($path); // $dir == 'public/images/portfolio/i-vis'
```

If you need even more information - there is [`pathinfo()`](http://bg.php.net/pathinfo)

```
$info = pathinfo($path);
var_dump($info);
```

produces

```
array(4) {
    ["dirname"]=>
    string(29) "public/images/portfolio/i-vis"
    ["basename"]=>
    string(5) "1.jpg"
    ["extension"]=>
    string(3) "jpg"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(1) "1"
}
```

So `$info['filename']` gives you the file without the extension.

Comment: This is cool, can we go one step further and find just the filename without the extension...

Answer (score 2):

```
echo basename($string);
```

Take a look at the [basename](http://php.net/basename) function.

Answer (score 1):

alternative solution. Just a bunch of explodes

```
$str='public/images/portfolio/i-vis/1.jpg';
$s = end(explode("/",$str));
print "filename " . $s."\n";
$e = explode(".", $s );
print "without extension: $e[0]\n";
```